# how to express "indefinite distributive numerals" ("several dollars each")? is aliquoteni classical?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice

In answer to the question *Quotiens?* (How many times), one can respond with *aliquotiens* (several times). But for the question *Quoteni?* (How many of each), can he come up with *aliquoteni*?

For I can't find *aliquoteni* in classical sources, but only very few attestations from Medieval sources ([e.g.](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yi7Qxg_AAAwC&pg=RA1-PA241&lpg=RA1-PA241&dq=aliquoteni&source=bl&ots=M_MArInHc7&sig=ACfU3U0UL2sdOCe0QVp_7G0EqX5afb7aCA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidnoTV9fjxAhWk_7sIHVQOAQYQ6AEwBnoECAwQAw#v=onepage&q=aliquoteni&f=false)). Maybe this word was used in classical times but due to its rarity, it didn't survive in our extant texts? Or there was alternative way of saying that?

Originally, I wanted to express the innocent "several camps". It seems the distributive is needed there, as *castra* is plural-form but really singular ([A&G 137.b](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/distributives)). But maybe *aliquot castra* would do?

Answer (score 2):

*Aliquot* as an indefinite adjective is common and is very suitable for your purpose.
Here are some examples taken from archaic and classical authors:

1. Cato, *orig.* fr. 128 Peter: *interim **aliquot** <p>au<ca> **castra** feci*
2. Plaut. *capt.* 161: *eorum sunt **aliquot genera** Pistorensium*
3. Cic. *Cluent.* 168: *dico illum [...] **aliquot dies** aegrotasse et ita
   esse mortuum*
4. Cic. *Brut.* 169: *sunt **aliquot orationes** Asculi habitae*
5. Liv. 2,19,3: *gliscens iam per **aliquot annos***

Other examples in the *Thesaurus linguae Latinae* s.v. [*aliquot*, col. 1616,36-69](https://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#5699).

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure however, if all the examples would use a distributive if the number were defined.  for example it seems *aliquot* might be replaces with *tres* (*tres orationes*/ *tres annos* and not *terni annos*).  But The example with *castra* indeed looks promising.

Comment: Because castra is (usually) a plural-only noun, the first example in your list is really the only one that's relevant to the question.

Comment: So I think I have misinterpreted the purpose of the question and I apologize. As an indefinite distributive numeral adjective aliquot could be fine, as the example of Cato I cited (which however is the result of a textual restoration) would demonstrate. However, tres is not a distributive numeral like ternus (but beware: ternOS annos and non ternI annos). As far as I know, in classical Latin there is no indefinite distributive adjective that translates 'some at a time'.

Answer (score 1):

Searching "aliquot castra" I happen by luck to find an old article ([Rand, Edward Kennard. "On a Passage in Virgil's First Eclogue." The Classical Journal 2.3 (1907): 125-128.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3287175.pdf)). in which the issue at hand is mentioned (tersely unfortunately).

In that paper a passage from the Ecoluge is dealt. For our need however, the relevant line is:

> post aliquot mea regna videns mirabor aristas

The word *arista*: when appears in plural might mean harvest. In that sense it is very similar to *castrum* that its plural has singular meaning.

Now, it is without question that *aliquot aristas* should be taken together. The question is whether *aristas* following *aliquot* might have the plural meaning of harvest and thus yield the meaning "(post) several harvests" i.e, (after) some time.   Or *aliquot aristas* should mean several conrns (i.e, the singular/regular meaning of *arista*). We read in the article:

> *Arista* means "an ear of corn," and the plural may well mean "a harvest," as Conington admits. He thinks, however, that aliquot distributes the new singular again. **But how would the Romans say "several camps," if not *aliquot castra*?** Claudian thought the new meaning of the plural so much of an entity that he modified it by the ordinal *decimus*, not by the distributive, as the rule enjoins. (emphasis mine)

So  it seems the author and other modern and ancient commentators did not seem to be alarmed by the fact that *aliquot* is used together with the plural-meaning (harvest), as they seem to acknowledge no other alterative of saying this like *aliquoteni*. Claudian even departs from the Law (A&G 137.b) above and use *decimas* he views harvest as a single unit. Even Conington, who interprets *aristas* here as corn, apparently didn't come up with strong grammatical argument to rule out the meaning of *aliquot aristas* as several harvests.

So overall it brings some evidence that *aliquot* can be used instead the theoretical *aliquoteni* (gives rise however to an ambiguity - that hopefully should be solved by context, though in this case from Virgil the context wasn't strong enough.)